# Error querying with Presto

Tags: cloudera, presto

I'm trying to run presto against CDH 4.3 and getting the following error message:

```
presto:default> SHOW TABLES;
Error running command: Response does not contain a JSON value
```

Connectivity between servers (inside EC2) has been checked with telnet and works properly. The server is running properly as far as I can tell. Here some relevant lines (./launch run):

```
2013-11-13T08:37:57.875+0000     INFO   main    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector  Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:18080
2013-11-13T08:38:01.037+0000     INFO   Discovery-2 io.airlift.discovery.client.CachingServiceSelector  Discovery server connect succeeded for refresh (collector/general)
2013-11-13T08:38:01.053+0000     INFO   Discovery-1 io.airlift.discovery.client.CachingServiceSelector  Discovery server connect succeeded for refresh (presto/general)
2013-11-13T08:38:02.737+0000     INFO   main    com.facebook.presto.importer.PeriodicImportController   Periodic Importer not enabled.
2013-11-13T08:38:06.389+0000     INFO   main    io.airlift.bootstrap.LifeCycleManager   Life cycle starting...
2013-11-13T08:38:06.390+0000     INFO   main    io.airlift.bootstrap.LifeCycleManager   Life cycle startup complete. System ready.
2013-11-13T08:38:06.392+0000     INFO   main    com.facebook.presto.server.PluginManager    -- Loading plugin /home/ec2-user/presto-server/data/plugin/hive-cdh4 --
2013-11-13T08:38:06.548+0000     INFO   main    com.facebook.presto.server.PluginManager    -- Finished loading plugin /home/ec2-user/presto-server/data/plugin/hive-cdh4 --
...
2013-11-13T08:38:11.642+0000     INFO   main    io.airlift.bootstrap.LifeCycleManager   Life cycle starting...
2013-11-13T08:38:11.648+0000     INFO   main    io.airlift.bootstrap.LifeCycleManager   Life cycle startup complete. System ready.
2013-11-13T08:38:11.698+0000     INFO   main    com.facebook.presto.metadata.CatalogManager Added catalog hive using connector hive-cdh4
2013-11-13T08:38:11.705+0000     INFO   main    com.facebook.presto.metadata.CatalogManager Added catalog jmx using connector jmx
2013-11-13T08:38:11.942+0000     INFO   main    com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer ======== SERVER STARTED ========
```

Any help with this would be deeply appreciated. These are the configuration files:

config.properties

```
coordinator=true
datasources=jmx,hive
http-server.http.port=18080
presto-metastore.db.type=h2
presto-metastore.db.filename=var/db/MetaStore
task.max-memory=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://localhost:18080
```

jvm.config

```
-server
-Xmx1G
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p
-XX:PermSize=150M
-XX:MaxPermSize=150M
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=150M
-Xbootclasspath/p:/home/ec2-user/presto-server/lib/floatingdecimal-0.1.jar
```

node.properties

```
node.environment=production
node.id=ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff
node.data-dir=/home/ec2-user/presto-server/data
```

catalog/hive.properties

```
connector.name=hive-cdh4
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:10000
```

Comment: how are you starting your presto CLI?

Comment: I'm starting it like this: `./presto --server localhost:18080 --catalog hive --schema default`

Comment: I don't see the point. You said you're using CDH 4.3 but uri of the metastore is address of Amazon WS.

Comment: What's your point? I am using CDH 4.3, it's just hosted on EC2 and that's why the uri looks like that...

Comment: I see that you provide TCP port 10000 for metastore instead of 9083. Are you sure about these values? Because 10000 are for hiveserver2 service commonly and metastore use 9083 as default port. Could you check that?

Comment: @DamienCarol I haven't been trying this since originally posting this question. I'll try in the next few weeks again and see if that actually helps. Thanks!